# Web crawler to extract in between the list

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am writing a web-crawler in python. I wish to get all the content in between `<li> </li>` tags .For example:

```
<li>January 13, 1991: At least 40 people <a href ="......."> </a> </li>
```

So here I want to :

a.)extract the date- and convert it into dd/mm/yyyy format

b.)the number before people.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1)
h2 =soup.find_all("li")
count = 0
while count < len(h2):
    print (str(h2[count].get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
    count += 1
```

I can only extract the text right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the text with `.text`, [split the string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) *by the first occurence of `:`*, convert the date string to `datetime` using [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) specifying existing `%B %d, %Y` format, then format it to string using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) specifying the desired `%d/%m/%Y` format and extract the number using `At least (\d+)` regular expression where `(\d+)` is a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) that would match one or more digits:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = '<li>January 13, 1991: At least 40 people <a href ="......."> </a> </li>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

date_string, rest = soup.li.text.split(':', 1)

print datetime.strptime(date_string, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print re.match(r'At least (\d+)', rest.strip()).group(1)
```

Prints:

```
13/01/1991
40
```

Comment: What if in the data object you have defined to have the full html code and not just <li> tag.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia then you would need to locate the element using `find()`, `find_all()` or `select()` or other methods that `BeautifulSoup` provides - consider asking a separate question if you have difficulties finding the desired element. Thanks.

Comment: Check this question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884490/web-crawler-to-extract-from-list-elements