# Extract relevant links and storing them as .csv file

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page1 = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_stampedes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1)

events = soup.find('span', id='20th_century').parent.find_next_sibling('ul')
for event in events.find_all('li'):
    try:
        date_string, rest = event.text.split(':', 1)
        print datetime.strptime(date_string, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        print event.text
```

Using the above approach I can extract dates from < li > tags. I wish to extract the cite links as well. Problem is each < li > tag has many links. Though cite has class defined "cite:. I still can't get the full links.
I end result to store these as table where each row comprises of the date and cite link. (in .csv format).
Refer question-[Web crawler to extract from list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884490/web-crawler-to-extract-from-list-elements/27885003?noredirect=1#comment44171446_27885003)

Comment: Do you want to store all the links under each date?

Comment: Yeah. So each row in the csv file should look like <date><link>.

Comment: And what if a row doesn't have a link at all?

Comment: I would prefer in that case the entry for the link in that row is blank.

Comment: Thanks. Please have look at the new comment, I seem to not correctly mention the link to extract which was my primary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that you can use as a start. It creates a csv file in the following row format:

```
date,link
```

It would skip a row if there was an error extracting a date component. Currently, for the sake of an example, it works with a "20th century" paragraph:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org'
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_stampedes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# build a list of references
references = {}
for item in soup.select('ol.references li[id]'):
    links = [a['href'] if a['href'].startswith('http') else urljoin(base_url, a['href'])
             for a in item.select('span.reference-text a[href]')]
    references[item['id']] = links


events = soup.find('span', id='20th_century').parent.find_next_siblings()
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for tag in events:
        if tag.name == 'h2':
            break

        for event in tag.find_all('li'):
            # extract text
            try:
                date_string, _ = event.text.split(':', 1)
                date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%B %d, %Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            except ValueError:
                continue

            # extract links and write data
            links = event.find_all('a', href=lambda x: x.startswith('#cite_note-'))
            if links:
                for link in links:
                    for ref in references[link['href'][1:]]:
                        writer.writerow([date, ref])
            else:
                writer.writerow([date, ''])
```

`output.csv` after running the script:

```
19/09/1902,
30/12/1903,
11/01/1908,
24/12/1913,
23/10/1942,http://www.ferrovieinrete.com/doc_storici/GalleriaGrazie.pdf
09/03/1946,
01/01/1956,
02/01/1971,
...
```

Comment: Thanks! works fine. But what you are doing extracts the link specified within text. The problem is that I have is to extract the link at the end of text specified as for example [35]. In this case the href tag doesn't specify the link directly but mentions it as <a href="#cite_note-34"><span>[</span>34<span>]</span></a>.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia updated, first building a reference dictionary to find reference links. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks so much. Great Idea. Couldn't find this approach anywhere.